# Need help creating a custom event handler

Tags: c#, event-handling

```
new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.eventFunction)
```

the above sends an 'object sender' and 'MouseEventArgs e' to my event function. I need to send another object with it, but if I use:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.eventFunction(object, MouseEventArgs, objectINeed));
```

It doesn't work. It just says there is an invalid argument. Even if I blatantly send it an object, MouseEventArgs, object.

Can anyone provide any insight?

Comment: What is the object you want to pass?

Comment: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-custom-event-handlers

Comment: But, I think you should be able to inherit from `MouseEventArgs`, or `EventArgs` and create your own.

Comment: The code snippets you posted make little sense, that's just code that cannot compile.  The mouse events are generated by code that's built into the .NET framework.  In response to notifications sent by Windows.  That code will only ever pass two arguments to the event handler, a sender and a MouseEventArgs.  The only things it knows about the Windows notification.  There's just no way to get that code to send something else, not without re-writing the .NET framework code or fundamentally changing the way Windows reports mouse events.

Comment: Its just adding an event handler to a windows form object. In this instance a calendar. it would be ...calendar += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.eventFunction);

Answer (score 0):

No cause the object sender should already have the information you need to pass to the event. The event is attached to the object.

You might create a method that can be called from within the event to go and retrieve the object or data you need.

Or you might make the scope of the object you need reference too high enough so that its already available to the event.

Comment: I thought about doing that. I would have to create an object with the scope of the class because the object I want to send gets dynamically created and only has the scope of the particular method I am calling it from. I just wanted to avoid it because there can be more than one at any given time, so I would have to change the implementation a little. I can get access to it somehow because it still exists when I leave the method. I just wanted to see if there was a way I was missing that would allow me to send it with the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler((s, e) => this.eventFunction(objectINeed, e));
```

But why do you need that?